# How to print the array format data of a table using for loop in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

******Here Is My Code*************

```
           <form name="f1" method="post" action="middle1.php">
```

**Here It Is Getting The Row Data From DB into array format and i placed dat data into variable data1**********

```
                              <?
                              $user=$_SESSION['user'];
                              $data1= array();
                              $data1= $obj->pcode($user);
                              $dat=  count($data1);
                              // echo $dat;
                              ?>
```

**********Here Using The data1 variable am trying to print the all rows present in the DB******

```
                        <?if($data1!=''){
                                   for($i=0;$i<=$dat;$i++){
                                 ?>
                         <tr> <td width="52" height="28" align="center"bgcolor="#E1E1E1" class="cal_txt_black">
```

*Here is the problem how can i mention that it hav to print the first row then so...on in the php echo statement****

```
                              <input name="pcode" type="" value="<? echo $data1['projectcode']; ?>" size="1"  border="0" style="background-color:D8D8D8"></td>
                                <td width="52" height="28" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="cal_txt_black" style="border-right:1px solid #D8D8D8;"><input name="mon" type="text" value="<? echo $data1['mon']; ?>" size="1"  border="0" style="background-color:White"></td>
                                    <td width="52" height="28" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="cal_txt_black"><input name="tue" type="text" value="<? echo $data1['tue']; ?>" size="1"  border="0" style="background-color:White"></td>
                                    <td width="52" height="28" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="cal_txt_black"><input name="wed" type="text" value="<? echo $data1['wed']; ?>" size="1"  border="0" style="background-color:White"></td>
                                    <td width="52" height="28" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="cal_txt_black" ><input name="thu" type="text" value="<? echo $data1['thu']; ?>" size="1"  border="0" style="background-color:White"></td>
                                    <td width="52" height="28" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="cal_txt_black"><input name="fri" type="text" value="<? echo $data1['fri']; ?>" size="1"  border="0" style="background-color:White"></td>
                                    <td width="52" height="28" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="cal_txt_black"><input name="sat" type="text" value="<? echo $data1['sat']; ?>" size="1"  border="0" style="background-color:White">
                                            <td width="52" height="28" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="cal_txt_black" style="border-right:1px solid #D8D8D8;"><input name="sun" type="text" value="<? echo $data1['sun']; ?>" size="1"  border="0" style="background-color:White"></td>

                                            <td width="52" height="28" align="center" bgcolor="#D8D8D8" class="cal_txt_black" style="border-right:1px solid #ffffff;" ></td>
                                            <td width="52" height="28" align="center" bgcolor="#D8D8D8" class="cal_txt_black" style="border-right:1px solid #ffffff;"></td>
                                            <td width="52" height="28" align="center" bgcolor="#D8D8D8" class="cal_txt_black" style="border-right:1px solid #ffffff;"></td>


                               <td><input name="save1" class="btn_login" type="submit" value="Save" align="center" formaction="middle2.php"></td>         
                            </tr>
                               </form> 
                                   <? }

                                   }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple use the $i variable in th loop

```
for($i=0;$i<=$dat;$i++){
  ?>

<input name="pcode" type="" value="<?php echo $data1[$i]['projectcode']; ?>" size="1"  border="0" style="background-color:D8D8D8"></td>


<?php } ?>
```

Comment: can you do print_r($data1) and paste value here?

Comment: it is printing first row but problem is am unable to loop it to print the remaining..

Comment: no need of loop just print $data1 before loop and paste the array here

Comment: Array ( [0] => employee [username] => employee [1] => PAP [projectcode] => PAP [2] => 6 [mon] => 6 [3] => 7 [tue] => 7 [4] => 8 [wed] => 8 [5] => 8 [thu] => 8 [6] => 10 [fri] => 10 [7] => 90 [sat] => 90 [8] => [sun] => )

Comment: Also one suggestion for using valid html as some time it may generate problems. (You must use put all you tr code between table block. Also it is better if you put closing form tag outside loop, Because in current scenario it can be skipped if no rows found)